# Calling functions from Rust DLL with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dll, rust, stdcall

I'm trying to create a Rust DLL and call those functions from 64bit Excel (Windows 10 and Office 365).

Currently my lib.rs looks like this:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "stdcall" fn square(x: f64) -> f64 {
    {x * x}
}
```

I'm compiling with command:

```
rustc --crate-type=cdylib lib.rs
```

My VBA code looks like this:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function square Lib "C:\Users\user\rust\excelfunctions\src\lib.dll" (ByVal x As Double) As Double

Sub testsquare()
    MsgBox square(10)
End Sub
```

Excel is "helping" me to debug this by giving always the same error:

```
Run-time error '48':

File not found. C:\Users\user\rust\excelfunctions\src\lib.dll
```

I've obviously checked that the file is there and I can see the function with DLL Export Viewer. If I replace the file with C library, I can make the function work. I've managed to make this work with Haskell as well, so I know Excel is talking with the outside world, it's just not saying anything more specific when giving the error message.

I've spent a lot of time with this and tried all possible combinations I could come up with. I would highly appreciate if the person who answers this would first double check that the proposed solution really works in his/her machine, so we don't end up with a very long ping pong of questions and "no" answers (been there already). It's just not possible to list here all the possible variations I have already tried.

EDIT: I had Rust Nightly installed in Settings -> Apps & features, which was messing my setup somehow. After uninstalling Nightly, everything works!

Comment: Are you sure that your bit-ness is correct, e.g. 64-Bit excel and 64-Bit rust toolchain target?

Comment: @ljedrz I think `cdylib` would be even more correct ^^ https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html

Comment: Fixed the type to dylib (have tried dylib, lib, cdylib, staticlib...). Sorry, but this is exactly what I was talking about in the end. My post represents the latest thing I have tried. There are just so many moving parts in this equation that we have to draw multidimensional matrix to represent all the possible combinations I should try. Replicating the situation on other computer is not hard since no dependencies is needed or anything.

Comment: And @hellow: yes, I'm using stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.

Comment: I have to say: *"Works for me"* if I use `cdylib` and the correct target... There is something wrong with your setup. Please triple check that the path is correct (use a simpler one, e.g. `D:\lib.dll`) and use `rustc --crate-type=cdylib --target=x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` (and verify that you are running a 64-bit Excel by looking at the task manager!)

Comment: Thanks @hellow for confirmation, now I know where to look. This was very helpful.

Comment: @hellow I could kiss your legs. When I tried to explicitly use --target flag, rustc was telling me that "target may not be installed" even though it was there and it was default as well. Then I saw that I had Rust Nightly installed in Settings->Apps&Features. I was wondering if that was messing my setup somehow and uninstalled that. Now everything works like a charm when using cdylib. Couldn't be happier to finally see this working!

Comment: Excel will tell you that the "path is not found" under several circumstances, including ones where the path is totally fine. I generally find that using Windows Event Logs, or a tool like procmon, to debug Excel is more efficient in those situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had Rust some old explicitly installed Nightly in Settings -> Apps & features (of Windows 10), which was messing my setup somehow. After uninstalling Nightly, everything works.

Comment: I don't get what do mean by "settings -> Apps & features". There is no such option neither in rust, nor in rustup. I think you are using some kind of gui, but it doesn't have anything to do with rust itself..

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer a bit to be more explicit. I had some kind of manually installed Rust Nightly package in Apps & features and thus I had two separate installations (one via rustup + manual App). I can't recall in what point did I install that, but uninstalling that solved the problem. Did this explain the problem?

Comment: I must have used some old installers from time before rustup. For example from here you can still find links to Rust 1.0 Windows installers that still work: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/book/installing-rust.html